# Java Xpath to exclude child in xml

Tags: java, xpath

My xml file is like below

```
<table id="553" name="Schedule Master">
<property name="dataSet">Schedule_Master</property>
                        <list-property name="boundDataColumns">
                            <structure>
                                <property name="name">SCHD_ID</property>
                                <expression name="expression">dataSetRow["SCHD_ID"]</expression>
                                <property name="dataType">decimal</property>
                            </structure>
                        </list-property>
                        <table id="585" name="SegmentInfo_Child">
                                        <property name="dataSet">SegmentInfo_Child</property>
                                                    <list-property name="visibility">
                                                        <structure>
                                                            <property name="format">all</property>
                                                            <expression name="valueExpr">Total.count() &lt; 1</expression>
                                                        </structure>
                                                    </list-property>

                          </table>                  
                        <table id="627" name="EnrollmentInfo_Child">
                                        <property name="dataSet">EnrollmentInfo_Child</property>
                                                    <list-property name="visibility">
                                                        <structure>
                                                            <property name="format">all</property>
                                                            <expression name="valueExpr">Total.count() &lt; 1</expression>
                                                        </structure>
                        </table>                  
</table>
```

So I want information only from my parent table that is  Schedule Master , which means my xml should look like below.

```
    <table id="553" name="Schedule Master">
    <property name="dataSet">Schedule_Master</property>
                            <list-property name="boundDataColumns">
                                <structure>
                                    <property name="name">SCHD_ID</property>
                                    <expression name="expression">dataSetRow["SCHD_ID"]</expression>
                                    <property name="dataType">decimal</property>
                                </structure>
                            </list-property>
</table>
```

so how can I achieve this using Xpath expression .
I had tried below expressions , but obviously they didn't helped

```
1) "//cell/table[1]"  
2) "//table[(descendant::table)]"
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: XPath cannot remove elements from XML... Do you want to get specific data from outer `table` only? If so, which data exactly?

Comment: yes @Andersson , only from outer table , I have updated the post with my desire result and yes I don't want to delete those sub tables rather with regex I need Outer table only

Comment: Do you need to extract values from outer `table` or you need to modify current XML DOM to remove everything except outer `table`?

Comment: I need to extract values from outer table

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract data (for instance `property` text value) from outer table only:

```
//property[count(ancestor::table) = 1]/text()
```

This won't match `property` nodes of inner tables as they have two `table` ancestors, so `count(ancestor::table) = 1` predicate will return `false` for them

Comment: I actually want the output in the way I have mentioned and the given expression will give only property but in actual it can have many items like property

Comment: As I have already said, you cannot remove nodes with XPath. You can use `//table[not(ancestor::table)]` to select required table, but you still might suffer from locating descendant nodes

Comment: Nope that didn't work , there should be something which will not give descendant node

Comment: You CANNOT select outer table excluding its child/descendant nodes (using XPath)! You can select it with ALL children only. You can "filter" descendants to exclude nodes from inner tables

Comment: @AutoJava: XPath is for *selection*; use XSLT if you need to *transform*.